# Using regex to determine straight (unordered hand)

Tags: regex

A straight in poker is five cards in a row, for example `23456` or `89TJQ`. With a "sorted" hand, the regex could be written as:

```
^(A2345|23456|34567|45678|56789|6789T|789TJ|89TJQ|9TJQK|TJQKA)$
```

It's a bit verbose but straightforward enough. However, would it be possible to generate a (sensible) regex if the hand was unordered? For example, if the hand was `52634` or `JQ89T`??

One possible way would be to use a `?=.*<item>` lookahead (which would essentially be "unsorted"), for example:

```
^(?:
     (?=.*A)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)
    |(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)
    |(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)
    |(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)
    |(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9)
    |(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9)(?=.*T)
    |(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9)(?=.*T)(?=.*J)
    |(?=.*8)(?=.*9)(?=.*T)(?=.*J)(?=.*Q)
    |(?=.*9)(?=.*T)(?=.*J)(?=.*Q)(?=.*K)
    |(?=.*T)(?=.*J)(?=.*Q)(?=.*K)(?=.*A)
)
.{5}$
```

Are there other / better approaches to finding if a straight exists using regex only?

Comment: Why regex? Just for fun, or is there any technical reason?

Comment: @ZorgoZ just for fun / as an academic exercise.

Comment: What about [this](https://regex101.com/r/W8FLvZ/2): `(?!(.).*\1)(?:[A2345]{5}|[23456]{5}|[34567]{5}|[45678]{5}|[56789]{5}|[6789T]{5}|[789TJ]{5}|[89TJQ]{5}|[9TJQK]{5}|[TJQKA]{5})`?

Comment: @ctwheels Wow, you should make that an answer

Comment: @ctwheels that's super neat -- how does that one even work?

Comment: @ctwheels nvm, it validates `56779` as a straight :-/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ya I just realized, gimme a second to fix and I'll put it in an answer

Comment: @ctwheels by the way, here is a link with some examples to test: https://regex101.com/r/Jibs2T/1

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 you should post your full regex somewhere, I'm curious to see what it looks like (you have multiple questions for the poker regexes) - I'd love to make an all-encompassing regex for all the rules and cases you have (to the haters, yes, regex isn't the best tool, but it really is fun).

Comment: @ctwheels -- thanks, I have a couple more "individual" questions and then I'll start combining them into more all-encompassing/challenging ones!

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 sweet, let me know when you post it, I would love to have a crack at it.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I had some fun: https://regex101.com/r/UMPM0w/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

See regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/W8FLvZ/3)

```
(?!.*(.).*\1)(?:[A2345]{5}|[23456]{5}|[34567]{5}|[45678]{5}|[56789]{5}|[6789T]{5}|[789TJ]{5}|[89TJQ]{5}|[9TJQK]{5}|[TJQKA]{5})
```

This works by first using a negative lookahead to ensure that the string doesn't contain any duplicates `(?!.*(.).*\1)`. Then it matches 5 characters from any of the straight possibilities.

```
 (?!.*(.).*\1)
#^^^         ^ negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match
#   ^^         match any character any number of times
#     ^^^      capture a character into capture group #1
#        ^^    match any character any number of times
#          ^^  match the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capture group
```

Against `JQQ89`, it works as follows:
  - `.*` matches `J`
  - `(.)` captures `Q`
  - `.*` matches nothing
  - `\1` tries to match `Q` (and succeeds)
  - Negative lookahead has a match, so fail the match.

Comment: I was trying to crack this problem myself but my solution was wayyyy off the radar. This is really a super impressive use of regex.