# Using regex to calculate poker hands [Part 1]

Tags: regex

I'm going to ask a series of questions of increasing complexity to see how far we can get using regexes (and regexes only!) to analyze poker hands. Perhaps I'll put the successive answers into something like a blog post to demonstrate the power of regexes when used creatively.

Is regex the right tool for this job? **Absolutely not**! Any programmatic string processing could do this task a million times better and more readably. Having said that, I'm hoping that the answers to these questions will show someone how powerful regexes can be with a little bit of creativity and also, perhaps where even with some creativity it cannot be done without some programming logic.

**Goal:** the goal in these posts is to construct a single regex expression to determine the rank of someone's five-card poker hand. For example, "AKAKA" would be a full house.

**Cards:** for this question, we'll use 52 cards displayed as follows:

```
2♦2♠2♥2♣    3♦3♠3♥3♣        4♦4♠4♥4♣    5♦5♠5♥5♣    6♦6♠6♥6♣    7♦7♠7♥7♣     8♦8♠8♥8♣
9♦9♠9♥9♣    10♦10♠10♥10♣    J♦J♠J♥J♣    Q♦Q♠Q♥Q♣    K♦K♠K♥K♣    A♦A♠A♥A♣
```

For the first part of the question, we'll see if a user has a 2- 3- or 4-of-a-kind. For example, as a starting point:

```
.*(?<four_of_a_kind>.)(.*\1){3}
|.*(?<three_of_a_kind>.)(.*\1){2}
|.*(?<two_of_a_kind>.).*\1
```

The above expression is not perfect (that is, it's wrong in a lot of cases), but I've provided it as a sort of template for how we can determine the highest rank based on alternation for a given 5-card hand.

**Question:** check if the user's current hand has 4-of-a-kind, 3-of-a-kind, or a pair. For example, the answer would produce:

```
AAKJ4
==> 
{
    'four_of_a_kind':   None, 
    'three_of_a_kind':  None, 
    'pair':            'A'
}

AKQKK
==>
{
    'four_of_a_kind':   None, 
    'three_of_a_kind': 'K', 
    'pair':             None # this could say either None, '', or 'K'
}
```

Comment: (that's awesome) - but the problem is that there isn't an actual question in your question :P

Comment: @ctwheels updated the questions a bit.

Comment: Is `10` used or `T`? I see some of your other questions using `T` instead of `10`.

Comment: Your "starting point"  regex is just wrong: `\1` backreferences try to match Group 1 that is `four_of_a_kind` here. You might have meant `(?<four_of_a_kind>.)(?:.*(?P=four_of_a_kind)){3}|(?<three_of_a_kind>.)(?:.*(?P=three_of_a_kind)){2}|(?<two_of_a_kind>.).*(?P=two_of_a_kind)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for pointing that out, yes that's correct it should be using the named groups.

Comment: @ctwheels either T or 10 is fine. I think 10 is usually how it's represented when looking at a poker book or tutorial.

Comment: Why use regex for this ? Can't it be done using 4 - 13 character array's, one for each suite ? Read each successive card and put it into the right slot in the appropraite suit array. Then start from the highest like a straight flush, and work down to a simple pair. It seems fairly easy.

Comment: @x15 yes, this can very easily be accomplished in any programming language, but I think the user is trying to learn regex, so they're asking specific questions related to their created patterns to identify how they work and where they fail. Although it might seem atypical, the user is trying to further their understanding of a common language tool.

Comment: Most of the problems you want to solve would be made significantly less complex if you ordered the hand. Is there a reason you don't want to?

Comment: Is there going to be suite characters interlaced ? `♦♠♥♣` Then to test for a flush would be `^(?=.([♦♠♥♣])(?:.\1){4})`

Comment: @x15 yea suit/flush would be something like `^.*(?<suit>[♦♠♥♣])(.*\k<suit>.*){4}$`, I'll leave that for another question though. The suit shouldn't matter for pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that will find each of the hand patterns that are required for poker. It builds on @ctwheels [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826075/using-regex-to-determine-straight-unordered-hand/58826336#58826336) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826075/using-regex-to-determine-straight-unordered-hand) and @WiktorStribiżew [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845139/using-regex-to-calculate-poker-hands-part-1#comment103965137_58845139) to this one, adding regex for a high straight (which can be checked against a flush to see if the player has a royal flush), full house and two pair.

```
^(?=.{5}$)
 .*?
 (
  (?<high_straight>(?!.*(?<hscard>.).*(?P=hscard))[TJQKA]{5})|
  (?<straight>(?!.*(?<scard>.).*(?P=scard))(?:[A2345]{5}|[23456]{5}|[34567]{5}|[45678]{5}|[56789]{5}|[6789T]{5}|[789TJ]{5}|[89TJQ]{5}|[9TJQK]{5}))|
  (?<four_of_a_kind>.)(?:.*(?P=four_of_a_kind)){3}|
  (?<full_house>(?=.*(?<fh_card1>.)(?=(?:.*(?P=fh_card1)){2}))(?=.*(?<fh_card2>(?!(?P=fh_card1)).)(?=.*(?P=fh_card2))).+)|
  (?<three_of_a_kind>.)(?:.*(?P=three_of_a_kind)){2}|
  (?<two_pair>(?=.*(?<tp_card1>.)(?=(?P=tp_card1)))(?=.*(?<tp_card2>(?!(?P=tp_card1)).)(?=.*(?P=tp_card2))).+)|
  (?<two_of_a_kind>.).*(?P=two_of_a_kind)
 )
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RArZ8M/2)

The full house and two pair regex work by using a lookahead to match a card value that appears 3 times (for a full house) or twice (for two pair). A second lookahead is then used to check for a *different* card value (using a negative lookahead for the first card value) which occurs twice.

Here's an example of how you would use this in PHP:

```
$hands = array('AJKTQ', '43A52', 'AAKAA', '58888', '58585', 'AKKKA', 
               '22333', 'AK9AA', '78444', '93233', '64886', '662TT', 
               '67898', '432A4', 'KQA34', '34628');

foreach ($hands as $hand) {
    echo "$hand: ";
    preg_match_all("/$regex/x", $hand, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if (!count($matches)) {
        // here you should check for a flush
        echo "high card";
    }
    else {
        $matched_hand = array_filter($matches[0], function ($v, $k) { 
            return !empty($v) && !is_numeric($k); 
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
        switch (key($matched_hand)) {
            case 'full_house':
                echo "full house {$matches[0]['fh_card1']} over {$matches[0]['fh_card2']}";
                break;
            case 'two_pair':
                // here you should sort for the highest pair
                echo "two_pair {$matches[0]['tp_card1']} over {$matches[0]['tp_card2']}";
                break;
            case 'four_of_a_kind':
            case 'three_of_a_kind':
            case 'two_of_a_kind':
                echo key($matched_hand) . " " . current($matched_hand);
                break;
            default:
                // here you should check for a straight flush or royal flush
                echo key($matched_hand);
                break;
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
AJKTQ: high_straight
43A52: straight
AAKAA: four_of_a_kind A
58888: four_of_a_kind 8
58585: full house 5 over 8
AKKKA: full house K over A
22333: full house 3 over 2
AK9AA: three_of_a_kind A
78444: three_of_a_kind 4
93233: three_of_a_kind 3
64886: two_pair 8 over 6
662TT: two_pair T over 6
67898: two_of_a_kind 8
432A4: two_of_a_kind 4
KQA34: high card
34628: high card
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/s1Yo0)

Comment: Looks like the `high_straight` is covered in the `straight` part `[TJQKA]{5}` All you need to know now is if its a flush.

Comment: @x15 the reason I separated it out is because a `high_straight` that is also a flush is a `royal flush` as opposed to a `straight flush`. But yes, it doesn't need to be in both regex and I will remove it from the latter. thanks

Comment: So, who wins the pot given 5 hands ? Remember, regex only .

Comment: @x15 it could be done but would be insanely messy, requiring duplicating all the regex for each player in order of hand value. Also would need adding code to detect a flush which requires info about the suits in a hand.

Comment: A flush test should just be an extra assertion check, example  `a flush would be ^(?=.([♦♠♥♣])(?:.\1){4})` or similar.